# Animation on side menu bar using program

Tags: objective-c

https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu This is link of RESideMenu.

I am new to ios and i am working on new project in which i have made this kind of side menu bar. But one things which i want is that the window which is going back must get tilt on one side.

Actually I want one side to get decrease in size like flipkart app in ios. So can you please tell me if there is some way to fix this by doing any coding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a `CATransform3D` to the `UIView`'s `layer` property `transform`. An affine transform is a transform in which all sides of the `UIView` remain parallel. You will need to apply a non affine transform because the top and bottom of your view will not be parallel during the flip effect. You will need to use the underlying `UIView`'s `CALayer` `transform` property to apply the `CATransform3D`. You can access this property through the `layer` property on your view object. FYI, books have been written about Core Animation, so it is not a light topic especially for a beginner, but as you can see from the code below it is quite simple to apply a 3D rotation to your view.

```
//Transform
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity; 

//Modify the perspective transform
transform.m34 = - 1.0 / 500.0; 

//Rotate
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, M_PI_4, 0, 1, 0); 

//Apply transform to the layer
self.layerView.layer.transform = transform;
```